# $.ajax combining with $.ajaxSetup default settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a way of keeping track of current Ajax Requests which involves **$.ajaxSetup()**, and counting beforeSends & completes.

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcpDESIGNS/UJmuw/)**

```
var ajaxProcs = 0;

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend : function () { ajaxProcs++; },
    complete   : function () { ajaxProcs--; }
});
```

The problem is, if any given **$.ajax()** call has beforeSend or complete it will throw off the correct count of Ajax requests running.

For example, this would overwrite it, and **not add 1** to the ajaxProcs count.

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend : function () { /* blah blah */ }
});
```

---

**Is it possible to have BOTH ajaxSetup AND the $.ajax Override run?**

Comment: You can overwrite the jQuery ajax function and add your own independent code to do the counting. Very ugly and unreliable but possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var ajaxProcs = 0;
$(document).ajaxSend(function(){
  ajaxProcs++;
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
  ajaxProcs--;
});
```

This will run on every jQuery ajax call, regardless of what callbacks you bind to the individual requests.

Comment: Should you not be using `ajaxSend` and `ajaxComplete` instead because  `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` will fire only once if there are multiple requests going on at a time?

Answer (score 4):

How about this, let's try **beforeSend()** function as a sample..

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(){
        console.log('execute another beforeSend() function'); 
    }
});
```

Then this is your Ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend : function () { 
        console.log('execute beforeSend() function');
        if('beforeSend' in $.ajaxSettings){
            $.ajaxSettings.beforeSend();
        }
    }
...
```

And now it will execute the both functions

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

`ajaxSetup()` provides default values for parameters that can be passed to the `ajax()` function. They only apply as defaults and not when supplied in the actual `ajax()` call.

JQuery's `ajaxStart()`, `ajaxSend()` and `ajaxComplete()` are things you might want to read about. They are called before and after each ajax call.

There is a `global` option on the individual `ajax()` call that will disable those global functions though.

Not really a complete answer because it is overridable but maybe helpful.

Comment: I forgot I was using `$(document).ajaxStart()` and ajaxStop() for this also someplace! This works perfectly, and fun note: they can't be overridden, they both run. Here's the same example with 2 ajaxStart/ajaxStop's: http://jsfiddle.net/mcpDESIGNS/UJmuw/1/

Answer (score 1):

Because of how jQuery is designed I think your best bet is to make a rule to call the ajaxSetup function manually from the beforeSend. Even if jQuery had a more OO approach you would still have to call the parent anyway - it won't magically call itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrcJ7/

```
var ajaxProcs = 0;

var setupObj = {
    beforeSend : function(xhr) { ajaxProcs++; console.log('Increased to: ' + ajaxProcs); },
    complete   : function() { ajaxProcs--; console.log('Decreased to: ' + ajaxProcs); }
};

$.ajaxSetup(setupObj);

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://fiddle.jshell.net',
    beforeSend : function (xhr) { 
        setupObj.beforeSend(xhr);
    }
});
```